# Trace what Application is Going through HAproxy

Tags: mysql, haproxy

I have this setup where several applications are going through the load balancer (HAproxy) and accessing the MySQL database.

```
Several applications -> HAproxy -> MySQL database
```

I would like to know which specific application is accessing the database. When I did a show processlist on the database, it shows the IP of the HAproxy (of course). Then I tried to do lsof on haproxy and mysql database but it didn't help me (or I just don't know to interpret the results properly). And finally I checked the haproxy logs but it didn't show anything.

Thanks.

Comment: This would be easier if you can reconfigure applications to use separate accounts to log into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to trace haproxy connections back to specific processes on various machines.  This dinky little hackery looks on the haproxy machine for a host that you give it.  It then goes over to the source machine and looks for the connections through to the backend databases.

The most basic part is running the `echo 'show sess' | socat stdio unix-connect:/tmp/haproxy` on the haproxy server itself

```
#!/bin/bash
# comments here:

haproxy='<your haproxy target>'

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
echo ""
echo "usage: db_trace_haproxy_sessions.sh <hostname>"
echo "looks at connections from <hostname> to load balanced database and traces them back to processes"
echo ""
exit
fi

ip=`host $1 | awk '{print $4}' 2>/dev/null`
if [ "$ip" == "found:" ]
then
echo ""
echo "couldn't resolve $1"
echo ""
exit
fi

IFS="
"

for i in `ssh $haproxy "echo 'show sess' | socat stdio unix-connect:/tmp/haproxy | grep     $ip"`
do
# output example:
#0x2cd2780: proto=tcpv4 src=10.210.50.104:50791 fe=mysql be=mysql srv=db302 ts=04 age=1d11m calls=5 rq[f=909202h,l=0,an=00h,rx=7h59m,wx=,ax=] rp[f=109202h,l=0,an=00h,rx=7h59m,wx=,ax=] s0=[7,18h,fd=32,ex=] s1=[7,18h,fd=52,ex=] exp=7h47m

echo ""
db=`echo $i | awk '{print \$6}' | cut -d "=" -f2`
src=`echo $i | awk '{print \$3}' | cut -d "=" -f2`

echo "Source Connection: $src ... connected to $db"

ssh $1 "ps=\`netstat -naltp | grep $src | awk '{print \$7}' | cut -d "/" -f1\`; ps aux |     grep \" \$ps \" | grep -v grep"
done;
echo ""
```

Output looks like this:

```
db_trace_haproxy_sessions.sh appserver

Source Connection: 10.210.50.103:37114 ... connected to database319

root     19300  1.0  0.0  53944 16180 pts/0    S+   Feb19  16:02 /usr/bin/perl somePerlScript.pl 

Source Connection: 10.210.50.103:37115 ... connected to database142

root     19301  5.4  0.0  53940 16160 pts/1    D+   Feb19  81:41 someapachethread
```